# Selenium Everything is ok but it throws me error

Tags: python, selenium

Hello I was trying to code a program but now im stuck.

- Actualy I trying to get a button but when I do that it throw error (`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=mainMenu]/div[3]/div[2]/a"}`
  )
- I tried others forms like CSS
- Everything is ok so idk how to fix it
- Here is code => `https://pastebin.com/ZQ7Ha11r`
- Here is element code => `https://pastebin.com/ymHHUGAj`
- I don't think here is Iframe

Please help me <3

Comment: So you managed to login, then get this error after page loads?

Comment: I logged and then i try to go to mail menu, then I try to get create new messenge button @BarrythePlatipus

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code (minimal reproducible example) in your question body, not on pastebin.
You should also wait for each element to load properly, and also change

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=mainMenu]/div[3]/div[2]/a").click()
```

with

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainMenu"]/div[3]/div[2]/a'))).click()
```

In case the element you want to click in has `Utwórz wiadomość` text, you should consider locating it by partial text, like the elements above it.

Comment: I wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainMenu"]/div[3]/div[2]/a'))).click()
  File "C:\Users\ds072\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I cannot help you more without actually seeing the page. I tried to fix your incorrect XPATH expression (you forgot the quotes), and give you some pointers. Have a look at my code, see how elements are located, they try again. @GamingwithDayfit

Comment: When I click to open main messange menu button it's open a new tab, maybe this is problem. What do you think?

Comment: I think your XPATH selectors (after you login) are incorrect, but I cannot verify it without a login. @GamingwithDayfit

Comment: @BarrythePaltipus I will get u my password and login but u must give me your discord

Comment: @GamingwithDayfit, try copying and pasting the **full** page HTML - after you login, to pastebin, then give me the pastebin url.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xFPH2m9Y here is it

Comment: That pastebin only contains the `<head>` element of the page. Are you sure that's the complete page HTML? @GamingwithDayfit

Comment: @BaryythePaltipus sorry, my mistake here is complete one https://pastebin.com/B4GESN3S

Comment: There is no element with id `mainMenu` in that page. @GamingwithDayfit

Comment: I do copy xpath from element so idk whats go wrong, what i shold type them? class name also dont work :C

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248738/discussion-between-gaming-with-dayfit-and-barry-the-platipus).